# When do we use Scope and When QueryParam in API designing?

Tags: api, rest, scopes, query-string

We have a endpoint which returns JSON output. Few consumers requested for this endpoint. But a specific consumer requested only a part of the payload. So, in this case, should we use scope to authorize and also for slicing the information?

Requested as below:
/endpoint1  (with scope user1) -> give {shape:square, area:16, perimeter:16 }

/endpoint1 ( with scope user2) ->  gives {shape:square}

When we wanted to share only few info, could we use scope for that ?

We also understood that QueryParam is used only to filter like e.g give all shapes with square or rectangle.

Is our understanding correct ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Doing it by scope is something you can do, but I rather do this for visibility reasons (admin, super user, user, guest). In your case, I think adding a scope for one customer is an overkill.

I would probably do it like that:

```
/endpoint1/shape
```

or

```
/endpoint1/?fields=shape
```

In the end, it's an opinion based thing since all methods would lead to the desired result.

Comment: May I know whats the visibility reason? could you explain this?

Comment: Imagine the endpoint /users/ - admins can see every user, super users only the users which are assigned to them, a user and guest can't see anything.